# Protractor - Unable to launch firefox with capabilities and multiCapabilities in config file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs

**I am trying to launch the firefox browser with this code, my code for chrome is working fine. But with firefox getting trouble**

I have launched chrome with both way capabilities and multicapabilities and it working fine but when I try to do same with firefox. IT is throwing error.

```
   capabilities: {
        'browserName' : 'firefox',
        //'safari.options': { technologyPreview: true }
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: ['--safe-mode'],
        },
        //'acceptSslCerts' : true
        //directConnect: true
    },
```

**Below is the log**

HMvpandeyJ9MD6N:e2e-test vinaypandey$ npm run test:local

```
> e2e-test@0.0.1 test:local /Users/vinaypandey/b-backbase-portal/e2e-test
> protractor configuration/local.conf.js

(node:19320) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[15:20:29] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[15:20:29] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:20:32] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[15:20:32] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: Unable to determine type from: H. Last 1 characters read: H
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'AHMvpandeyJ9MD6N', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:891:5f91:8d75:94f9%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.4', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:580:13)
    at /Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:360:15
    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
    at asyncRun (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2652:27)
    at /Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
[15:20:32] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 100
npm ERR! e2e-test@0.0.1 test:local: `protractor configuration/local.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 100
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the e2e-test@0.0.1 test:local script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vinaypandey/.npm/_logs/2020-08-07T09_50_32_476Z-debug.log
AHMvpandeyJ9MD6N:e2e-test vinaypandey$ npm run test:local

> e2e-test@0.0.1 test:local /Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test
> protractor configuration/local.conf.js

(node:19345) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[15:20:42] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[15:20:42] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver

/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:83
          Error('Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at ' + url));
          ^
Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:58197/hub
    at onError (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:83:11)
    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
    at asyncRun (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2652:27)
    at /Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at acquireSession (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:62:22)
    at Function.createSession (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:295:12)
    at Driver (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js:271:38)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:71:26)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:182:43)
    at /Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:255:30
    at _fulfilled (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/vinaypandey/i-backbase-portal/e2e-test/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
[15:21:28] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! e2e-test@0.0.1 test:local: `protractor configuration/local.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the e2e-test@0.0.1 test:local script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vinaypandey/.npm/_logs/2020-08-07T09_51_28_162Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out!

refer below config.js file configuration.

use capabilities or multiCapabilities and comment out other one.

```
exports.config = {
        specs: ['spec.js'],

        capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'firefox',
            'moz:firefoxOptions': {
                args: ['--safe-mode']
            }
        },
        multiCapabilities: [
            {
                'browserName': 'chrome'
            },
            {
                'browserName': 'firefox',
                'marionette': true
            }],
        directConnect: true
    };
```

Comment: firefox browser is getting launched but, but no URL is passed in the browser.